# Hidden link For SEO and back link for our clients site we developed

Tags: seo, backlinks, blackhat, footer

We are a web design and development Company. We create many site and we have lot of portfolio items.

Normally we put link in footer of sites for we developed as very small text. Some client and US don't like to pull it in some sites. They may ask to remove and in some site it wont look good so we don't prefer to put in all.

So can we add a link back to our site as display none or hidden property or font size 1? Is it a black hat SEO technique that Google don't like? Will they ban us?

Answer (score 1):

Search engines have penalized those actions for years.

Do you really need a link on every page? Why not one link on one page like the "About" page for the company?

Comment: This is misleading, there isn't a penalty as such just for having a sitewide link to credit work in the footer of a site. If it is keyword rich anchor text and unnatural however then yes, it could have negative consequences. Sitewide links carry minimal weight in terms of SEO and [were devalued as such back in 2012](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTjN9x-by-I).

Comment: The question is, "So can we we add a link back to our site as display none or hidden property or font size 1?" That type of action has been penalized for many years.

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry, that approach can result in a penalty.

Comment: Also consider that Google does not like site wide external links at all anymore and links from footers *does effect* SEO for both sites. See https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356?hl=en where is says *Widely distributed links in the footers or templates of various sites*. Google cannot tell if this is manipulation easily and abuses have made this a Google no no. There is better Google page that is very explicit on external footer links, but I cannot find it quickly.